# Why does a non-physical magnetic field break the law for the force on a magnetic dipole?

Tags: electromagnetism

References (e.g. [this one](http://www.physicsinsights.org/force_on_dipole_1.html)) usually say that the force on a magnetic dipole in a magnetic field is

$$\vec{F} = \nabla\left(\vec{\mu} \cdot \vec{B}\right) $$

So consider a circular loop in the $xy$ plane with current going around it. Suppose the $B$ field is in the $z$ direction, but $\frac{\partial B}{\partial z} \neq 0$.

Then the formula for the force is non-zero, but the force by the Lorentz force law is zero.

I suppose the problem is that the $B$-field I described isn't physical, since is has non-zero divergence, but where does that break the derivation of the law for the force on a dipole?

Comment: Though it's clear that your field configuration violates Maxwell's Equations, I'm having trouble seeing intuitively why this field isn't physical. Why couldn't you create a field like this with, for example, a solenoid whose resistance steadily increases (and current correspondingly decreases) along its length?

Comment: @probably_someone two different resistors connected *in series* would still have the same current through them, or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: What do you mean the Lorentz force law gives zero force?

Answer (score 0):

*Answer rewritten due to misunderstanding the quesiton.*

The fact that the field you propose has a non-zero divergence breaks the derivation of the dipole force law at equations 10 through 12. The force on a wire loop parallel to the $x-y$ plane only occurs due to the transverse magnetic fields, namely $B_x$ and $B_y$ as seen in Equation 10.
$$f_z = -|\mu|(\partial_yB_y + \partial_xB_x)$$
Then, by assuming that the field is divergence-less (Equation 11)
$$\partial_xB_y + \partial_xB_x + \partial_zB_z = 0$$
we can simplify the force equation as (Equation 12)
$$f_z = |\mu|(\partial_zB_z)$$
A magnetic field that has a gradient along the z-axis must have gradients along the perpendicular directions to remain divergence-less. These perpendicular fields provide the Lorentz force on the wire loop.

Comment: "There seem to be two wire loops in your question." No. "The paragraph after that considers the wire loop that generates the magnetic field" No, I just imagined an external magnetic field and didn't discuss its source. "The Lorentz force is not zero in the reference article." I know but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking about the situation described in my question. "Just because ∂Bz/∂z≠0 does not mean the divergence is non-zero. " Yes it does, because my question also said "Suppose the $B$-field is in the $z$-direction."

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub I've rewritten my answer now that I understand what you were going for.

Answer (score -1):

For the force acting on the current loop lying in the $xy$ plane to be non-zero, the magnetic field gradient should have a non-zero component in the $xy$ plane, so $\frac{\partial B}{\partial z} \neq 0$ condition is not sufficient.

Here is a relevant quote from your reference article, where the gradient of the magnetic field is assumed to be in $y$ direction:

> If the gradient of B in the y direction is nonzero, then the forces
>   shown in figure 2 will not cancel.